# qTip2 hide if empty content

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I load the text for the tooltip from a custom tag, data-tooltip. I'd like the tooltip to be hidden if the data-tooltip is not present. Is this possible?

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAswt/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu a').qtip({
        content: {
            attr: "data-tooltip"
        }
    });
});
```

The qtip2 documentation says this for using "text" instead of "attr":

```
Custom functions that return no valid content will still cause the tooltip to be created! Replace these with an each() loop if this is not the desired behaviour.
```

If you look at the use of "attr", it says:

```
If no valid content is found within the elements attribute, and content.text is not defined, no tooltip will be rendered.
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, but generates warnings in Chrome: `qTip2: Unable to locate content for tooltip! Aborting render of tooltip on element: [Object object]`

Comment: Yep, that's what's supposed to happen. I just looked in qtip2's source code and there's a simple log() call with that message when there is no content to render (as it points out). It's simply a warning that was intentionally put in place to let the developer know - no error and no breaking of code, it's just normal!

Comment: Yes, I just noticed myself, I even get that by using the default title attribute instead. Thanks!